not able tio bind reactive form data to radio button
i am currently working on angular 14 reactive form , where i need to bind an option to set of radio buttons , i am unable to bind the selected option even though the formcontrolname exsists and has the value of specific form control
<mat-radio-button *ngFor="let element of item?.data" [formControlName]="item?.name" [value]="element?.id">
    {{ element?.name }}
</mat-radio-button> </div>

this is my piece of code which renders an radio button control but isnt getting binded to the form.value too upon changing i have also rendered text boxes which r working fine

Did you mean to write [formControlName]="element.name" by any chance?

you have to use mat-radio-button-group.

@MojtabaNejadPoorEsmaeili u are absolutley correct i have tried that acheived desired behaviour ,

@Cuzy that piece of code is correct the issue is with using mat radio button group
